# Conditional accept-language redirect within an <If> directive possible?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, apache2.4

## What I want to achieve?

I want to redirect to `/de/` if the homepage (`/`) is called and the HTTP header `Accept-Language` begins with `de` of the visitor's browser but only for specific domains.

## Here's my starting point:

As I have many domain specific redirect rules, I have multiple `<If>` directives. The following code snippet is reduced to a minimum.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on

    # Redirect serveral domain aliases
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?mydomain\.com$ [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?my\-domain\.com$ [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?anotherdomain\.com$
    RewriteRule .* https://www.mywebsite.com/en/products/overview/ [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(karriere|jobs)\.areal\-domain.at$
    RewriteRule .* https://www.mywebsite.com/de/ueber-uns/karriere/ [R=301,L]

    # Redirect language DE for homepage only of www.mywebsite.com
    # (the following rule is  outside of the following otherwise it will not work actually
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/?$
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^de [NC]
    RewriteRule ^$ /de/ [R=301,QSA,L]

    <If "req('Host') =~ /(live.mywebsite.com|www.mywebsite.com|mywebsite.com|mywebsite.docker)/">
        RedirectMatch 301 ^/$ /en/
        RedirectMatch 301 ^/contact(/)?$ /en/about-us/contact/
        RedirectMatch 301 ^/customer-support(/)?$ /en/service-and-support/
    </If>

</IfModule>
```

## This is my problem:

The apache v2.4.38 server does always send a HTTP status code 500 if I put the rewrite for the language redirection into the `<If>` directive as shown in the next snippet:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on

    # ...

    <If "req('Host') =~ /(live.mywebsite.com|www.mywebsite.com|mywebsite.com|mywebsite.docker)/">
        # Redirect language DE for homepage only of www.mywebsite.com
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/?$
        RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^de [NC]
        RewriteRule ^$ /de/ [R=301,QSA,L]

        RedirectMatch 301 ^/$ /en/
        RedirectMatch 301 ^/contact(/)?$ /en/about-us/contact/
        RedirectMatch 301 ^/customer-support(/)?$ /en/service-and-support/
    </If>

</IfModule>
```

## What is the reason for this behaviour?

I read the documentation, but I couldn't find any information about my scenario.